# Adding asterisk before and after a particular word in a sentence in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, string-interpolation

I want to add two asterisk '**' before and after a particular word in a sentence. For example, if the sentence is "He enjoys playing cricket in summer" and target word is 'cricket'. The final output string should be "He enjoys playing **cricket** in summer".
I am not able to do this explicitly. please suggest me a way to do this string modification in python.

Comment: `"He enjoys playing cricket in summer".replace('cricket', '**cricket**')` ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried splitting entire sentence into words, and appended asterisk before and after the word but it considered those asterisk as separate words and added spaces when joined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is for various sentences according to user input:

```
targetword = input('target word')
fullsentence = input('full sentence')
if targetword in fullsentence:
    fullsentence = fullsentence.replace(targetword, f'**{targetword}**')
    print(fullsentence)
    # print(f'{fullsentence[0:fullsentence.index(targetword)]}**{targetword}**{fullsentence[fullsentence.index(targetword) + len(targetword) : len(fullsentence)]}')
else:
    print('target word does not exist')
```

Notes: I changed the if conditioning. I completely forget that you could have that exact word at the beginning or at the end of the sentence itself.

*I changed the way I add the asterisk by .replace() as the other commenters have suggested. Seems nicer than my version.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this solution. This works as I needed but just one issue. The print statement inside if prints with the asterisk around the target word. But when I print the fullsentence outside the loop, It is still the normal sentence. I guess the modification is not stored in the variable 'fullsentence'.

Comment: because I purposely left the variable ``fullsentence`` as it is.
as for what you want (updating the variable ``fullsentence`` to the one with **) see edit to my code

Answer (score 1):

As a comment says you can use str.replace().

```
s = "He enjoys playing cricket in summer"
print(s.replace('cricket', '**cricket**'))
```

If you want something a bit more generic.

```
import re

def star_re(orig_string, star_string):
   new_string, count = re.subn(f'({star_string})', r'**\1**', orig_string)
   return new_string

def star_replace(orig_string, star_string):
   return orig_string.replace(star_string, f'**{star_string}**')

s = "He enjoys playing cricket in summer"

print(star_re(s, 'cricket'))
print(star_replace(s, 'cricket'))
```

The only advantage of the regex version is that you could make it more tailored to only match on word boundaries, or something.

Comment: So, the first function star_re() will add asterisk to the target word, right? And then in the next method it will just replace the target word.
In my task, I wont be having \*\*cricket\*\* target word. It will be only 'cricket'. So I wont be able to execute replace function directly.

Comment: They should have the same output and the functions should work the same way.  I believe I ran the program and that's what I saw and I don't see anything wrong in my example, but let me know if you ran it and got different results.  The functions do not replace in line, so the variable 's' is never changed.

Answer (score 1):

Every `string` in python has a built in `replace` method that you can use to replace a specific phrase with another phrase

### The general form is:

```
string.replace(oldvalue, newvalue, count)
```

---

### Parameter values:

| Parameter | Description | Required? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| oldvalue | The string to search for | Yes |  |  |
| newvalue | The string to replace the old value with | Yes |  |  |
| count | A number specifying how many occurrences of the old value you want to replace. Default is all occurrences | No |

---

### The code:

```
print("He enjoys playing cricket in summer".replace('cricket','**cricket**'))
```

**OR**

```
my_string = "He enjoys playing cricket in summer"
print(my_string.replace('cricket','**cricket**'))
```